# Does Positional Interpolation Change Llama's Architecture?

Tags: large-language-model, llama

I'm currently exploring Meta's positional interpolation [method](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.15595.pdf), which aims to increase with minimal effort the context size of their large language model. This method extends the context length from **n x n** into **n′ x n′**. It achieves this by interpolating new token values in between existing ones.

My question: Does this interpolation technique necessitate changes to the underlying model architecture? Specifically, how does the self-attention matrix, configured as an n × n matrix, adapt to accommodate the extended context size of n′ x n′?

This is a theory question